# Difference between 類 and 類

Tags: kanji, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

What is the difference between 類 (unicode: 985e)  and 類 (unicode: f9d0)?

They look virtually identical (at least as rendered by my computer).
Rikaichan says that the former has 18 strokes and the latter 19 but I count 19 in both (rice (6)+ dog (4)+ page (9)).
On Wiktionary the latter redirects to the page for the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 類 = 米 + 大 + 頁
>   類 = 米 + 犬 + 頁

Naturally, 犬 has one more stroke than 大, so that 類 has one more stroke than 類.

The latter is a (常用外) variant of the former (but, as snailboat points out, is listed as 旧字体 variant in the 常用漢字表). The variant is also contained in the 人名用漢字 list.

Comment: It's listed as the 旧字体 of 類 on the 常用漢字表.  I think the simplified form 類 was made official in the 1949 当用漢字字体表, taking the place of the traditional form 類 (so perhaps 類 was a handwritten variant before then).

Comment: Thanks. It is strange how my computer displays them. For example I see clearly the difference in the title of this article, but, if I copy and paste them elsewhere, both are displayed with the "dog" primitive. I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Does somebody else have the same problem?

Comment: Where are you pasting them that they look the same?  I have a feeling it is a font issue.  This clearly shows the version with the dog primitive, even though it is the U+985e character: http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E9%A1%9E

Answer (score 2):

The first contains 大 rather than 犬, hence one less stroke.  They both mean kind/class/type, but I'm not familiar with the second Kanji.  Googling it returns results as if I'd entered the first one.